# Letsencrypt SSL showing warning message while typing domain with "www"

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, lets-encrypt

I added "mydomain.com" in Nginx and then I configured with "Letsencrypt" free SSL. Mydomain.com is showing protection but later on I added "www.mydomain.com" to my Nginx settings and now when I try to access my domain I get warning message from "letsencrypt". mydomain.com still works fine but the problem is with typing with www only.

Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A certificate that is valid for `mydomain.com` is not necessarily valid for `www.mydomain.com`, as they are different domains.

Let's Encrypt allows you to generate a certificate that is valid for multiple domains. Therefore you should set up a new certificate that is valid for both `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com`.

Comment: I know how to install the certificate...please provide a ref to renew an existing certificate on Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't believe you can add a new domain when renewing. You'll have to create a new certificate that includes both domains. If you can't see how to include additional domains, please tell us how you are creating the certificate.